# Show Data Horizontally in Table using PHP & MySQL

Tags: php, html, css

I'm trying to display data horizontally in a table by using PHP & MySQL. The code that I'm currently using is (Obviously all values will be called from MySQL but currently I have put static values):-

```
$query = "select * from bonusdetails where BonusType='Free Money' order by Validity ASC limit 0,3;";
$result = mysql_query($query);
echo '<table width="150" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#941010" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; float:left; color:#ffffff;">';

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
            echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td align="center" style="padding:2px 0 0 0;"><img src="abc.jpg" width="124" height="64"/></td>';
    echo '</tr>';

                echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td align="center" style="font-size:15px; padding:8px 0 0 0;">No Deposit Bonus</td>';
    echo '</tr>';

                echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td style="font-size:17px; padding:5px 0 0 0;" align="center" >CODE: STAR75</td>';
    echo '</tr>';

                echo '<tr>';
    echo ' <td align="center" style="padding:8px 0 5px 0;"><a href="#"><input name="more-details" type="button" style="background:url(images/more-details.png) no-repeat; width:102px; 
    height:27px; text-decoration:none; border:none; cursor:pointer;" /></a></td>';
    echo '</tr>';

    }

echo '</table>';
```

I'm getting output in this format: `http://www.casinobonustips.com/submitbonus/bonus.php`. is there a way to display the same data horizontally?

I will highly appreciate your assistance on this.

Thanks and Regards,
Devjeet

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP or MYSQL. This is a layout problem and hence of HTML&CSS.

Comment: Why do you use `TABLE` instead of simple `DIVS`? In this case is not table needed.

Comment: it looks like all you need to do is put all your <td>s in the same <tr>

Answer (score 0):

**What you have:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>A1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>B1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>C1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>A2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>B2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>C2</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>A3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>B3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>C3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**What you should have:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>A1</div>
            <div>B1</div>
            <div>C1</div>            
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>A2</div>
            <div>B2</div>
            <div>C2</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>A3</div>
            <div>B3</div>
            <div>C3</div> 
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ePMmx/1/

Do your styling to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to group `<td></td>` in one `<tr></tr>` to display them "horizontally", on the other hand, you are mixing "view" stuff with processing and retrieving the data, you maybe have to read about MVC pattern for better programming